# Azure Policy not assigning on tagged VM

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Overview: I am trying to assign a policy to VMs by LinuxFamily tag. For example - if the VM has tag LinuxFamily: debian then all policy definitions with policyRule below should be assigned.

I have a policies with the policyRule containing:

[image: Policy rule filter]

and a VM with the following tag:
[image: Tagged VM]

I've added the policies to an initiative. However, the initiative or policies within the initiative are not picking up the resource:
[image]

Edit- Full Policy Code / Steps to re-produce:

The Built-in Azure policy "Linux machines should meet requirements for the Azure compute security baseline" can be duplicated and the policyRule "if" changed to:

[image: Built-in policy]

Assigning this to an VM with produce the same result (ensure parameters are set to true)

Comment: HI @Sonny, kindly share the full policy code by editing the questions.

Comment: Please ensure to provide a brief overview of your requirement.

Comment: Hi, I've added overview & instructions to re-produce.

Comment: The policy provided is in image format and does not contain the full code. Please ensure to provide the complete policy code.

Comment: Is it your requirement to audit the resource if the 'LinuxFamily: debian' tag is not present on all VM resources with the policy?

Comment: No I am trying to audit the resource if the 'LinuxFamily: debian' tag **is** present on all VM resources with the policy

Comment: yes, If the tag is present on all VM resource, it will mark as **complaint** otherwise **non-complaint**?

Comment: No, I want it to run the compliance check on VMs that have the tag "LinuxFamily: debian". policyRule is the filter for resources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256860/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-sonny).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to audit the resource if the 'LinuxFamily: debian' tag **is** present on all VM resources with the policy.

Here is the **Azure Policy** to audit the resources and check if the **LinuxFamily: debian** tag is present on all `Azure VM` resources.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "tags['LinuxFamily']",
            "equals": "debian"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

I have 3 `Linux VMs` in my azure subscription. out of these, 2 have the tag **LinuxFamily: debian,** and 1 has a different tag.

The VM resource are having tag **LinuxFamily: debian** which are mark as **complain** and other **non-complain**.

[image]

**Policy compliance result:**

[image]

You can **filter** the VM resources by selecting the compliance state option in the  policy compliance section.

**For example** :  To filter compliant resources, select only `compliant`, and you will get all compliant resources as per the tag.

Comment: I'm not looking to audit whether a tag is on the VM. I'm looking to only assign the policy on VMs tagged "debian". 

E.g. Guest Configuration policy will only audit on debian VMs

Comment: You want to assign the policy to VMs that have the tag LinuxFamily: debian.